# Days remaining for next birthday and day of the next birthday

Tags: android

Can anyone help me how to calculate days remaining for next birthday by DOB along with the day ,the birthday occurs i.e, Monday or Tuesday or etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UPDATED CODE]**

Add these imports:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;



    final String strBDay = "2014/04/07";//"1990/04/07"; // Next Birtday date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date dt = null;
    try
    {
        dt = sdf.parse(strBDay);
    }
    catch (final java.text.ParseException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final Calendar BDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    BDay.setTime(dt);

    final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Result in millis
    final long millis = BDay.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis();

    // Convert to days
    final long days = millis / 86400000; // Precalculated (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    sdf.format(dt);

    System.out.println("Left days to bday: " + days);
    System.out.println("It will be       : " + days);
```

Output:

12-14 16:23:08.811: I/System.out(5253): Left days to bday: 113
12-14 16:23:08.811: I/System.out(5253): It will be       : Monday

**[VERSION FOR USING D.O.B.]**

And this is if you want to use your Date Of Birth:

```
    final String strBDay = "1990/04/07";//"1990/04/07"; // Next Birtday date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date dt = null;
    try
    {
        dt = sdf.parse(strBDay);
    }
    catch (final java.text.ParseException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final Calendar BDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    BDay.setTime(dt);

    final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Take your DOB Month and compare it to current month
    final int BMonth = BDay.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int CMonth = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    BDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, today.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    if(BMonth <= CMonth)
    {
        BDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, today.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);
    }

    // Result in millis
    final long millis = BDay.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis();

    // Convert to days
    final long days = millis / 86400000; // Precalculated (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    //final String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(BDay.getTime());
    final String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(dt);

    System.out.println("Left days to bday: " + days);
    System.out.println("It will be       : " + dayOfTheWeek);
```

Output:

12-14 16:48:11.801: I/System.out(5342): Left days to bday: 113
12-14 16:48:11.801: I/System.out(5342): It will be       : Monday

Comment: I checked it with birthdate "1990/04/07", instead of 114 days remaining  it gives me 8652 days for the birthdate...Pls help me

Comment: I updated my code (see). And please accept. Note that you must put your FUTURE birthday, not your date of birth. Anyway, it's not too hard to calculate it from your date of birth.

Comment: I added another version to let you use your DOB (That is, automatically calculates your future birthday).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Calendar class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html).

For example to get the day of the week, you'd type:

```
Calendar daymonthyear = Calendar.getInstance();
daymonthyear.set(birthdayYear, birthdayMonth, birthdayDay);
int dayOfTheWeek = daymonthyear.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

EDIT: Remaining days is obtained via simple subtraction of current day/month/year and the birthday day/month/year values. **However, be careful that you don't leave negative values in your formula**

Comment: thank u..... I am successful in getting the next day, but what about days remaining for the next birthdate